# Mesh not staying fixed to bone when moving

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, objects, bones

I have made a model mesh of a robot type with resricted rotations on speparate object parts.

So there are constraits ie thigh child of hip with Thigh Y and Z rotation locked ZYX Euler. (see pic)[image]

It is not compleat but was moving ok so i started to rig and then parent mesh to the bones.

I was following this link as a base for the animation.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4TkA5P5Qes

Now in pose mode some of the mesh objects do not stay fixed to the bones.(see pic)[image]

This is my firt attempt at 3D modeling and animation so i may have got a bit too ambitious and hopefully just made a simple mistake.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I seem to hava partialy solved the problem be deleting all the constrains on all the objects but am still having some trouble with a few of the objects that have been copied and are keeping their bone constaints and have mesh parts duplicated seperately